# Java JUnit testing not working with @Before annotation

Tags: java, junit

Heay com,

started with Java JUnit testing and got a problem regarding @Before annotation.

My setup:
Java 9
Eclipse Oxygen
JUnit 5

If i do my test like this

```
package junittesting;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import de.hsa.games.fatsquirrel.space.XY;

public class XYtest {
    private XY testXY = new XY(0,0);
    private XY addingVec = new XY(0,1);


    @Test
    public void addVec() {

        assert (testXY.addVec(addingVec).equals(addingVec));
    }

}
```

the test will run fine. But if i do my XY objects in the @Before annotation then it will end with an error. Nullpointer in the assert line.

```
    package junittesting;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import de.hsa.games.fatsquirrel.space.XY;

public class XYtest {

    XY testXY;
    XY addingVec;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testXY = new XY(0, 0);
        addingVec = new XY(0, 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void addVec() {

        assert (testXY.addVec(addingVec).equals(addingVec));
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In JUnit Jupiter it has become `@BeforeEach`.

Comment: Thanks mate should read the manual :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the [JUnit 5 manual](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations) states, you must use `@BeforeEach`. The old `@Before`annotation only works with version 4:

> `@BeforeEach` - Denotes that the annotated method should be executed before each `@Test` [...] in the current class; analogous to JUnit 4’s `@Before`.

Comment: In general, one should probably check that either JUnit 4 or JUnit 5 dependencies are included in a project. It makes life and hunting setup problems much easier.